# Is it possible to create depedent route in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have created multiple routes(say department, Employee) which takes input from file system folders(say department, Empployee) and process those files.

Now, I want to make them dependent. So, if I upload both emp.csv and dept.csv in those folders then it will process department file first and once complete it will start processing file for employee.

is there any way in camel to achieve this.

I looked at [Route startupOrdering and AutoStartup](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html) feature, but it will work only for the first time when starting routes. However, I need same behavior for entire route life.

Thanks.

```
<route id="b" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <from uri="file:/home/dev/code/Integration/RunCamleExample/src/main/resources/csv/Department?repeatCount=1&amp;noop=true&amp;delay=10000"/>
    <log message="Department data is : ${body}"/>
</route>
<route id="employee" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <from uri="file:/home/dev/code/Integration/RunCamleExample/src/main/resources/csv/Employee?noop=true&amp;delay=10000"/>
    <log message="Employee data is : ${body}"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use other logic to handle the task. Two simple ways to go:

1. Use [pollEnrich](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-enricher.html)

   - Use pollEnrich to collect extra resource (e.g. a file with known name in file system) once at the middle of a route
   - Flow: **Collect department files** (From Endpoint) --(for each department file from file system) -> **collect single employee file** (trigger pollEnrich once with known name) ----> **do anything else (if any)**
2. Use [ControlBus](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/controlbus-component.html)

   - Use ControlBus component to control the [status of routes](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/lifecycle.html) (only one of the route in 'start' status)
   - Flow: **Start route A** --(when route A complete its goal)-> **Suspend route A** ---> **Start route B** --(when route B complete its goal)-> **Suspend route B** ---> **Start route A** [loop back to head]

Answer (score 0):

Dependent route execution first can be achieved in Camel using "RouteContext".

Example: If route 'A' is executed before route 'B' then route 'A' should be defined as 'RouteContext' and route be is defined inside "camelContext" like below:

```
 <routeContext id="A" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="A">
         <from uri="file:/home/dev/code/Integration/RunCamleExample/src/main/resources/csv/Department?repeatCount=1&amp;noop=true&amp;delay=10000"/>
         <log message="Department data is : ${body}"/>
    </route>
 </routeContext>
```

Then regular "camelContext" should be defined with reference to this routeContext first.

```
<camelContext id="test" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeContextRef ref="A"/>
    <route id="B">
         <from uri="file:/home/dev/code/Integration/RunCamleExample/src/main/resources/csv/Employee?noop=true&amp;delay=10000"/>
         <log message="Employee data is : ${body}"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```